# Can't I write 'True' or 'False' in lowercase or sentence case in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice

I've been working on one table in LibreOffice Calc (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) and for that, I have to write 'True' or 'true' and 'False' or 'false' in some cells. However, whenever after writing 'True'/'True' or 'False'/'false', I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it automatically changes them to Uppercase i.e. 'TRUE' or 'FALSE'. This doesn't happen for any other text.

I tried changing the case by following [this link](https://help.libreoffice.org/3.3/Writer/Changing_the_Case_of_Text). However, I couldn't change it to either lowercase or sentence case. So, how can I do that? or it's not even possible? 'TRUE' and 'FALSE' are reserved keywords in LibreOffice Calc?

Comment: Did you try to put `'` before the word?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli yup, it worked. I didn't know that it would be such a subtle option. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to save arbitrary text in a *LibreOffice* Calc cell, you should prepend the text with `'`. Otherwise the text will be considered as a formula and some appropriate conversions will be applied.

Another method would be to first select the cell you want to enter text, then go to **Format → Cells... → Numbers** and in **Category** select **Text**, so that the data you will later enter into the cell will be interpreted as arbitrary text and not as a formula.